# Proof confusion or solving strategy?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof

I found myself reading a proof to $Claim X$ for which the proof involved the use of the Truth of $Claim Y$, later I found a proof to $Claim Y$ (from a different source) and was suprised to find that it involved the use of the Truth of $Claim X$. Of course I suspected/knew that there must be other ways to prove  atleast one of them, but as from my perspective it was a unique situation. (The Claims in question was "*Any polygon can be triangulated*" and "*The sum of all interior angles in a polygon is $180(n-2)$ degrees*") When i from my perspective overlooked the situation it seemed like none of either $Claim X$ or $Y$ have been proved as of yet, only that

Truth of $Claim X$ and reasoning led to Truth of $Claim Y$,

Truth of $Claim Y$ and reasoning led to Truth of $Claim X$,

i.e. Truth of $Claim X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ Truth of $Claim Y$

**Questions:** Do there exist problems which require you to create such a scenario as stated above and utilize it as a problemsolving strategy somehow OR is the situation just weird and should be avoided?

and

Given an equivalence between two claims such that "if $ClaimA$ is True then so is $ClaimB$", aswell as "if $ClaimB$ is True then so is $ClaimA$". If there is a way to prove $A$ directly which implies $B$, is the opposit always possible aswell, that is, is there then always a way to directly prove $B$ which implies $A$?

Also, the comments and answers below might be of help understanding what this is all about. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot prove $X$ using $Y$ when $Y$ is proved using $X$. That's not a strategy, it's a logical error. In your particular case each of those claims can be stated as depending on the number of sides of the polygon. Both are true for triangles. Then you might use a clever induction that proves each for $n$ sides using the other for $n-1$ sides. Check the proof you are reading for this kind of logic.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I believe that you might have misinterpret what I am asking or more likely my post lacks clarity. Anyhow, I don't mean that this is a strategy to prove X and Y hence my formulation: "...none of either ClaimX or Y have been proved ...". What I do wonder however is that, if this relation between X and Y, now that we know of it, might helps us prove/promotes the investigation of/achived a more desireable situation/be of use for something else (I do not know what) and if so, what would that be?

Comment: Also note that the proofs are from different sources, where the one source just proved claim X with the help of Y, and the other source proved claim Y with the help of X. They were not presented together one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct in suspecting that this equivalence can be a problem solving technique, especially when tackling very difficult problems.

As a simple example of this, suppose that you are attempting to find all rational solutions  of a family of biquadratic equations and suppose that, in the standard way, you have established an equivalence with rational points on a family of elliptic curves.
As part of your problem solving strategy you can now switch backwards and forwards between the two scenarios depending upon which seems more tractable for the problem in hand.

From what I have read, the proof of F.L.T. was a splendid example of switching between different viewpoints according to the difficulties that were arising in each possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question.

In the context you describe, each of theorems $X$ and $Y$ implies the other. Each seems to be of about the same level of difficulty. You know two sources, one of which proves $X$ first, using some geometric arguments, then deduces $Y$ essentially as a corollary. The other source does the reverse.

This kind of situation is common, and not at all weird. It is often instructive to provide both approaches, to make it clear that $X$ and $Y$ are (in some sense) at the same level of difficulty.

One classic example is Euclid's parallel postulate. Any of the following (and many more) could be taken as an axiom - then  the others would be theorems.

- Given a line and a point not on it there is just one line through the
  point parallel to the line.
- The sum of the angles of a triangle is two right angles.
- There are similar triangles that are not congruent.

Comment: That is interesting but not spot on, we've come this far so I am just gonna explain everything from the start. From Paul Zeitz's book "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving." on page 46 (book avaible as pdf)  there is an partial solution presented to the problem that the sum of the interior angles of any n-gon is 180(n - 2) degrees. It is proved by induction, but also with the help of triangulation. However, this is only presented as a partial solution because it remains to show that any polygon can be triangulated. The 2nd source is the page which discusses The Art Gallery Problem on Brilliant

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/guarding-a-museum/ . The complete proof is based on proving 3 claims, for which claim 1 so happens to be "Any polygon can be triangulated". Reading this you'll notice how they use the Theorem for interior anglesum for polygons: S=180(n-2). And that is what got me thinking. From my perspective again, (“not convinced” that either of these theorems are true of what I've read) you'll understand how it becomes a "logical error" for me to accept that they are both true. What just happend was new and seemed a bit chaotic, but also intuitively as a potential upside.

Comment: So I wanted to understand wether there was something more to it (from my perspective) other then just a logical error. Also, your help is very much appreciated.